# Why doesn't the compiler at least warn on this == null

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, null, this

Why does the C# compiler not even complain with a warning on this code? :

```
if (this == null)
{
   // ...
}
```

Obviously the condition will **never** be satisfied..

Comment: Wow... I guess I was shamefully **wrong** ...

Comment: though it requires (ill) use of System.Reflection.Emit you can end up in a situation where object.ReferenceEquals(this,null) is true. Personally I would spend to much time writing that kind checks in C#

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because you could [override `operator ==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) to return true for that case.

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this == null);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Running `new Foo().Test()` will print "True" to the console.

The other question here is: why doesn't the compiler issue a warning for `ReferenceEquals(this, null)`?  From the bottom of the above link:

> A common error in overloads of `operator ==` is to use `(a == b)`, `(a == null)`, or `(b == null)` to check for reference equality. This instead results in a call to the overloaded `operator ==`, causing an infinite loop. Use `ReferenceEquals` or cast the type to Object, to avoid the loop.

*That* might be answered by @Aaronaught's response.  And that's also why you should be doing `(object)x == null` or `ReferenceEquals(x, null)`, not doing a simple `x == null`, when you're checking for null references.  Unless, of course, you're sure that the `==` operator is not overloaded.

Comment: This is yet another reason why I wish C# didn't confuse reference and value equality.

Comment: @Jonathan: see the note at the bottom of that link: "A common error in overloads of `operator ==` is to use `(a == b)`, `(a == null)`, or `(b == null)` to check for reference equality. This instead results in a call to the overloaded operator ==, causing an infinite loop. **Use ReferenceEquals  or cast the type to Object, to avoid the loop.**"  (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: Since when does C# "confuse" reference and value equality?  `System.Object` even has the `ReferenceEquals` and `Equals` methods for when you want to be explicit.  The idea behind allowing the `==` operator to be overloaded is that you allow the object itself to decide which is appropriate.  The only real nuisance is that it's possible for the overloaded `==` operator and `Equals` method to behave differently (and as a class designer you should avoid such things).

Comment: Incidentally, there actually is a class (well, struct) that **already** overloads the `==` operator and specifically handles the `null` comparison: `Nullable<T>`. So this isn't just some bizarre corner case, there are legitimate reasons to do this (including the Null-Object Pattern).

Comment: In other languages, including VB, reference equality and value equality are different operators. This makes it clear what type of comparison you are doing and prevents many subtle errors.

Comment: or because this can actually be a null reference. (see my answer)

Answer (score 25):

> Wow... I guess I was shamefully wrong

I disagree. I think you still make a good point.

The compiler knows whether the comparison is going to go to a user-defined comparison operator or not, and the compiler knows that if it does not, then 'this' is never null.

And in fact, the compiler *does* track whether a given expression can legally be null or not, in order to implement a minor optimization on non-virtual method calls. If you have a non-virtual method M and you say `foo.M();` then the compiler generates this as "do a virtual call to M with receiver foo".  Why? Because we want to throw if foo is null, and a virtual call always does a null check on the receiver. A non-virtual call does not; we'd have to generate it as "check foo for null, and then do a non-virtual call to M", which is longer, slower, more irritating code.

Now, if we *can* get away without doing the null check, we do. If you say `this.M()` or `(new Foo()).M()` then we do NOT generate a virtual call. We generate the non-virtual call without the null check because we know that it cannot be null.

So the compiler has excellent data on whether a particular comparison to null will sometimes, always, or never succeed.

The question then is "if the compiler knows that a particular comparison will never succeed, why not generate a warning for it?"

And the answer is "sometimes we do, and sometimes we don't".

We do in this situation:

```
int x = 123;
if (x == null) ...
```

There is an equality operator defined on two nullable ints. x is convertible to nullable int. null is convertible to nullable int. So that equality operator is valid, and therefore is used, and is of course always false. The compiler gives a warning that the expression is always false.

However, due to a bug we accidentally introduced in C# 3, this code does NOT produce that warning:

```
Guid x = whatever;
if (x == null) ...
```

Same deal. The nullable guid equality operator is valid, but the warning is suppressed. I'm not sure if we fixed this bug for C# 4 or not. If not, hopefully we'll get it into a service pack.

As for "if (this == null)" I don't know why we don't warn for that. It certainly seems like a good candidate for a warning. The most likely explanation is to follow this logical syllogism:

- warnings are compiler features
- compiler features must be (1) thought of, (2) designed, (3) implemented, (4) tested, (5) documented and (6) shipped to you before you can take advantage of the feature.
- No one has done *any* of those six necessary things for this feature; we can't ship features that we never thought of in the first place.
- therefore, no such feature.

There are infinitely many compiler features that we haven't thought of yet; we've implemented none of them.

Another reason to not give a warning here is that we try to give warnings on code which is both *likely to be typed by accident* and *almost certainly wrong for a non-obvious reason*. "this == null" is not likely to be typed in by accident, and though it is almost certainly wrong, as you note in the statement of your question, it is *obviously* wrong.

Compare that to our "guid == null" -- that is likely to happen by accident, because a developer might accidentally think that Guid is a reference type. Guids are usually passed around by reference in C++, so this is an easy mistake to make. The code is almost certainly wrong, but it is wrong in a non-obvious way. So this is a good candidate for a warning. (Which is why it is so unfortunate that this is a warning in C# 2 but not C# 3, due to a bug we introduced.)

Comment: @Andrei - Eric has access to (in fact, has probably written some of) the C# source code due to his job.

Comment: Another reason for not giving a warning that this==null will always be false is that well it will not _always_ be false. (See my answer)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the condition really [**can** be satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451311/c-closures-over-class-fields-inside-an-initializer/2451335#2451335), at least in Visual Studio 2008.  They've fixed this behaviour in VS 2010, but it is not totally inconceivable that there might be another way to create such a condition.

(tl;dr version - in C# 3.5, it's legal to reference `this` from an anonymous function passed as a constructor argument, but if you actually try to use it, you'll find that `this` is `null`.)

Answer (score 3):

Though the code below is a bastard it's still all C#. an if you call Bar you will get an InvalidOperationException with the message null.

```
public class Foo
{
    static Action squareIt;
    static Foo() {
        var method = new DynamicMethod(
                                       "TryItForReal",
                                       typeof(void),
                                       Type.EmptyTypes,
                                       typeof(Foo).Module);
        ILGenerator il = method.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Foo).GetMethod("tryit"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        squareIt = (Action)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
    }

    public void tryit()
    {
        if (this == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Was null");
        }
    }

    public void Bar() {
        squareIt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This also falls in line with other warnings C# does (or not does for that matter) like:

```
if(true)
or 
if(1 == 1)
```

These will also always have the same result no matter what.

Comment: Well, sure, but if such code does result in *unreachable* code then that will produce a warning.