# Why is integer == null a valid boolean expression in C#?

Tags: c#, null, boolean, non-nullable

Why is `integer == null` a valid boolean expression in C#, if `integer` (variable of type `int`) is not nullable? (I'm not against it, in fact I like it, but I didn't know it was possible)

Comment: You do get a warning, something along the lines of "expression is always false".  As to why it's *allowed*, i.e., does not result in a compile time error... I suppose it's for the same reason this is allowed; `while(true)`

Comment: The C# compiler will at compile time optimize this to false when compiled in release mode (a `ldc.i4.0` ends up being in IL).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# okay with comparing value types to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972262/c-sharp-okay-with-comparing-value-types-to-null)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although `int` itself is non-nullable, there's an implicit conversion to `int?`, which *is* nullable.

At that point, if the struct declares an `==` operator with the same type on both sides, then that's lifted to work with nullable types too.

So this doesn't compile:

```
public struct Foo {}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo x = new Foo();
        if (x == null)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

... but if you give `Foo` some operators, it *does* compile, and without a warning:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public static bool operator ==(Foo x, Foo y) { return true; }
    public static bool operator !=(Foo x, Foo y) { return false; }
    public override bool Equals(object x) { return false; }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return 0; }
}
```

The operator invocation isn't included in the compiled code, because the compiler *knows* that the RHS is null.

So code of the form above (where `Foo` can be replaced by any non-nullable `struct`) has one of three outcomes with the MS C# 5 compiler:

- Warning CS0472 (e.g. with `int`)
- Error CS0019 (custom types which don't overload `==`)
- Clean compilation (custom types which overload `==`, including `Guid` and `DateTime`)

It's not clear to me why the compiler treats some "known" types differently to normal structs though. EDIT: As noted by Eric in comments, this is a known bug in the C# compiler, which is hopefully fixed in Roslyn.

Comment: Damn, that's weird! Maybe structs are the exception?

Comment: And trying to create your own implicit operator to convert it to `Nullable<T>` (eg `public static implicit operator Nullable<Foo>(Foo f)`) fails with compiler error [CS0555](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8xz60wc.aspx).

Comment: Re: it's not clear why known types are different from user defined types: it is a bug, probably introduced by me when I was refactoring parts of the compiler during C# 3.0. For some unclear reason the bug has never been fixed even though we've known about it for a long time now. I seem to recall I fixed it in Roslyn before I left but I don't recall exactly.

Comment: I also note that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177850/guid-null-should-not-be-allowed-by-the-compiler/2177971#2177971 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1972317/88656

Comment: And this one also has some similar analysis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464097/why-doesnt-the-compiler-at-least-warn-on-this-null/2481017#2481017

Answer (score 1):

As Ed mentions there's a warning, but the warning alludes to the reason: `int` can be auto-casted to `int?`, and `null` is a valid value for a variable of type `int?`.

Comment: skeet beat me by seconds. Damn you skeet!

Comment: You said that backwards. You meant to say that `int` can be *implicitly converted* to `int?`.

Comment: Ack. Thanks Eric. Corrected.